# Color aliases in lecturer.tex

Tags: color, presentations

It is my understanding that `lecturer.tex` uses its own strategy to manage named colors, but I would like to manage my own color palettes, so that I can just "switch" them; so, I would need an "alias" feature. This is currently not working. How could I accomplish that ? Any chance to make `lecturer.tex` work with xcolor?

Example: https://gist.github.com/evacchi/754988add09e34b714a39323f117b5ba